# How to predict a variable (distributed heavily to both ends) with two predictors?

Tags: regression, distributions, linear

I'm working on a psychological research project. In former data we asked participants to do a binary decision multiple times (accept or decline). Looking into the data, the acceptance rate per participant showed that most participants either accepted or declined every time.

Now, we want to see if we can predict if a participant is either an "accepter" or a "decliner" with two predictors, but I'm unsure which test to use to check this prediction.

Is it legit to run a simple linear regression? This seems to be weird because of the distribution of our variable.

Or is it a good idea to define descrete categories for the variable and put the participants either in a "accepter"-category, a "decliner"-category and a "something-between"-category? But how do you do this then?

Thank you for your efforts in advance!

PS: Here is a picture of the distribution we observed. 0 = declined, 1 = accepted.
[image]

Comment: So each patient was asked for a constant number of yes/no questions. Have you considered regarding that as a binomial process? In that case a binomial regression might make sense.

Comment: Wouldn't that just show me how my predictors predict if the participant says yes or no instead of if a person is a general yes-sayer or no-sayer?

Comment: The (obviously wrong) assumption of a binomial model is, that for every participant there is a constant probability of answering "yes". Wouldn't such a per-person-constant be the perfect measure of a participants yessayericity ? Binomial regression shows, whether your two indepents can predict the yessayericity if your loose assumption holds, that the probability to say yes or no is less dependent on the question and more a person's constant.